# Get CalendarFX entry from DateControl

Tags: mysql, database, javafx, calendar, javafx-8

I am a student and have been trying out the [CalendarFX](http://dlsc.com/products/calendarfx/) library for the past few weeks for my project.

I have been looking through the documents but I can't seem to figure out how to **get the newly created Entry** every time the user double-clicks the DateControl in the CalendarView FXML.

Not really part of my question above but, after getting the Entry I intend to store the Entry in a MySQL database and retrieve the list of entries back to an ArrayList.

I really appreciate any possible lead, hint or even technical help.

Answer (score 0):

When using CalendarFX applications need to provide one or more "Calendar" instances. Whenever the user double clicks on the view a new entry will be created and added to one of these calendars. You can add a listener to the calendars to receive an event when this happens.

```
calendar.addEventHandler(CalendarEvent.ENTRY_ADDED, e -> handleEvent(e));
```